Procedure to solve $\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos (\alpha x)}{x^2-1} dx$
I recently solved a complex analysis exercise that required to solve this integral using residue theory, but I don't know where to check for the correctness of the result I got, so I thought of sharing it here to see if I made any mistake.
To solve this integral, we first study the complex function $f(z) = \frac{\cos (\alpha z)}{z^2 - 1}$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant. This function has two first order poles in $z=1$ and $z=-1$; to study these poles, we can expand this function in a Taylor series around each pole:
$$
\begin{align}
z=1 &: f(z) \simeq \frac{1}{z-1} \left(\frac{\cos \alpha}{2} - \frac{2\alpha\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha}{4} (z-1)\right) \\
 z=-1&:f(z) \simeq \frac{1}{z+1} \left(-\frac{\cos \alpha}{2} - \frac{2\alpha\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha}{4}(z+1)\right)
\end{align}
$$
This series expansions have a radius of convergence that is, respectively $\mid z-1\mid < 2$ and $\mid z+1 \mid < 2$; moreover, this function will be entire when $\cos \alpha = 0$, that is for $z=k \frac{\pi}{2}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (the exercise asked for this as well).
From this series expansions, we get the residues of the function:
$$
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{Res}\left[f(z), z=1\right] = \frac{\cos\alpha}{2}\\
&\operatorname{Res}\left[f(z), z=-1\right] = -\frac{\cos\alpha}{2}
\end{align}
$$
The exercise then asked for
$$
\lim_{z\to \pm 1} f_I(z)
$$
where $f_I(z)$ is the function $f(z)$ for $\alpha : f(z)$ is entire. Using the series expansions, we can see that both the limits are equal:
$$
f_I(z=\pm 1)=\lim_{z\to \pm 1} f_I(z) = -\frac{2\alpha \sin \alpha  + \cos\alpha}{4}, \alpha =k \frac{\pi}{2}, k\in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Now the exercise asks to compute
$$
I(\alpha) = \mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos (\alpha x)}{x^2-1} dx
$$
We can immediately see that the integral $I(\alpha) = I(-\alpha)$ because of the parity of the cosine at the numerator, so we should compute that integral just for $\alpha \ge 0$. The idea here is to calculate the complex integral
$$\tag{1}
\lim_{\substack{R\to+\infty \\ r \to 0^+}} \frac{1}{2} \left[\oint_{\Gamma_{r,R}} \frac{e^{i\alpha z}}{z^2 -1} dz + \oint_{\Gamma'_{r,R}} \frac{e^{- i\alpha z}}{z^2 -1} dz\right] = \mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2- 1} dx
$$
where $\Gamma_{r,R}$ is a semi-circumference of radius $R$ in $\Im(z) > 0$ and radius $r$ around the points $z=\pm 1$, while $\Gamma'_{r,R}$ is just the same thing but in $\Im (z) < 0$, so that the part of those integrals where the functions are integrated on the arc of radius $R$ converges to $0$ for the Jordan's lemma. Because of this and because of the fact that the residues of $f(z)$ are one the opposite of the other, we get that
$$
\mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2- 1 } dx = 0
$$
This is true because the residues of the sum of those single exponential functions will be equal to the sum of residues of $f(z)$, which is equal to $0$.
I hope this is correct and feel free to point out anything. Thank you in advance for your help, I appreciate it a lot!
EDIT: After I finished writing this post, I thought about the validity of the final result and I went into the details of calculation, finding out that what I said is wrong; the correct result of the integral is valid for $\alpha\neq 0$ and:
$$
\mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2-1} dx = i\pi \cos(\alpha), \ \alpha \neq 0
$$
Also, what I said in Equation (1) is wrong; I should have said that from that limit in the left-hand side of Equation (1), we get that:
$$
\mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2 -1 } dx = \frac{i \pi}{2} \Big(\operatorname{Res}[E_1(z), z=\pm 1]- \operatorname{Res}[E_2(z), z=\pm 1]\Big)
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
&E_1(z) = \frac{e^{i\alpha z}}{z^2-1}\\
&E_2(z) = \frac{e^{-i\alpha z}}{z^2-1}
\end{align}
$$
I should have considered the case $\alpha = 0$ separately: this integral would result from integrating
$$
\lim_{\substack{R\to+\infty \\ r \to 0^+}} \oint_{\Gamma_{r,R}} \frac{1}{z^2-1} dz = 0 = \mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-1} dx + i\pi \operatorname{Res}\left[\frac{1}{z^2-1}, z=\pm 1\right]
$$
Since the sum of those residues is equal to $0$, then:
$$
\mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-1} dx = 0
$$
This should be the correct and full solution to the problem.
EDIT 2: I probably made some sign errors while calculating the residues, which are:
$$
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{Res}[E_1(z), z = 1] = \frac{e^{i\alpha}}{2}\\
&\operatorname{Res}[E_1(z), z = -1] = -\frac{e^{-i\alpha}}{2}\\
&\operatorname{Res}[E_2(z), z = 1] = \frac{e^{-i\alpha}}{2}\\
&\operatorname{Res}[E_2(z), z = -1] = -\frac{e^{i\alpha}}{2}
\end{align}
$$
so:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2 -1 } dx &= \frac{i \pi}{2} \Big(\operatorname{Res}[E_1(z), z=\pm 1]- \operatorname{Res}[E_2(z), z=\pm 1]\Big)\\
&=\frac{i\pi}{2} \left[\left(\frac{e^{i|\alpha|} - e^{-i|\alpha|}}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{e^{-i|\alpha|} - e^{i|\alpha|}}{2}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{i\pi}{2} \left[i \sin|\alpha| - (-i \sin|\alpha|)\right] =-\pi \sin |\alpha|
\end{align}
$$


Mathematica reports a result of $-\pi \sin|\alpha|$, which suggests some lingering sign error in your second solution. This would also make the $\alpha=0$ case more sensible. 2) I would suggest replacing $\cos(\alpha x)\to e^{i\alpha x}$ and recover the original result as the real part.


I did the calculation once again and I actually get $-\pi \sin \alpha$, so I guess this time I got it right. Thank you for posting this out.

The absolute value of $\alpha$ could come from the fact that when I say that the integral is equal to those exact residues with that sign, I'm implicitly giving a sign to $\alpha$ as well, which doesn't alter the result because if it was negative, the two complex integrals will change sign and compensate for the change in $\alpha$

You have $\cos(-\alpha x)=\cos(\alpha x)$, so the sign of $\alpha$ can't matter: the integral is an even function of $\alpha$.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.{\rm P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\alpha x} \over x^{2} - 1}\dd x\right\vert_{\alpha\ \in\ \mathbb{R}}}
\\ = & \
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\alpha x} - \cos\pars{\alpha} \over x^{2} - 1}\dd x\ +\ \overbrace{{\rm P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\alpha} \over x^{2} - 1}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\large= 0}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 2}\bracks{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\alpha x} - \cos\pars{\alpha} \over x - 1}\,\dd x -
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\alpha x} - \cos\pars{\alpha} \over
x + 1}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\alpha x}\cos\pars{\alpha} - \sin\pars{\alpha x}\sin\pars{\alpha} - \cos\pars{\alpha}\, \over x}\,\dd x\right.
\\[2mm] & \left.\phantom{a} -
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\alpha x}\cos\pars{\alpha} + \sin\pars{\alpha x}\sin\pars{\alpha} - \cos\pars{\alpha}\,\, \over x}\,\dd x\right]
\\[5mm] = & -\sin\pars{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{\alpha x} \over x}\,\dd x =
-\sin\pars{\alpha}\on{sgn}\pars{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{\verts{\alpha}x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
-\sin\pars{\verts{\alpha}}\ \overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\large\pi}}\ =\
\bbx{\color{#44f}{-\pi\sin\pars{\verts{\alpha}}}} \\ &
\end{align}
